# TextView onClick() not working

Tags: android, android-layout, onclick, textview

here's my code for main.xml

```
 <merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@id/container" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<include layout="@layout/tabs" />

<ScrollView
    android:fillViewport="true" 
    android:scrollbars="@null"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- first text_view -->
        <TextView 
            android:background="@color/grey"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/category" 
            android:id="@+id/category1" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="65dp" 
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:typeface="serif"/>

        <!-- first horizontal_scrollview -->
        <HorizontalScrollView 
            android:scrollbars="@null"
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" 
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content">

                <!-- image_view should be here -->

            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
</merge>
```

here's my code for tabs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:background="#333333">

<TextView
    android:textColor="@color/gradient_green"
    android:id="@+id/viewall"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:text="@string/view_all"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <TextView
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/pic"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/viewall"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:text="@string/pic"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here's the code inside the Main.java:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView all = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.viewall);
    TextView pic = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.pic);

    all.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView all = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewall);
            TextView pic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pic);

            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "VIEW ALL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            all.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.gradient_green));
            pic.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.white));
        }
    });

    pdf.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView all = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewall);
            TextView pic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pic);

            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "VIEW ALL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            all.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.white));
            pic.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.gradient_green));
        }
    });

  }
```

so, if I set the setContentView() in the Main.class or Main.java as setContentView(R.layout.tabs) instead of setContentView(R.layout.main), the onClick() works, what should I do or what's wrong with my code that hinders onClick() not to work?

Comment: i think these two statement should be somewhere else in oncreate or onstart methods     
     all = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.viewall);
     pdf = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.pic);
like
     all = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.viewall);
     pdf = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pic);

Comment: i'm trying to display tabs like Pulse News app and came up with this idea but i can't get it work

Comment: i got it working now, thanks for your answers guys, i sticked with my first post code...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use these

```
 all = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.viewall);
 pdf = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.pic);
```

in on create and then set

all.setOnclickListener(this) in oncreate() method too.Implement onClicklistener when it will show error. it will work like a charm.

**Edited**

```
TextView btn=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.accInfo);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //DO you work here
        }
    });
```

**Setting Clicklistenner to TextView will automatically make it clickable so no need of**

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Comment: In addition to what you mentioned above I had to call `btn.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);` to address the fact that the TextView would require a double-tap to actually fire the `OnClick` event. I don't know what might have changed in the last two years but this seems to be required in 4.4.2.

Comment: I get:
`The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})`

Comment: Look at your import,you should import android.view.View.OnClickListener;. I guess you import click for dialog listener

Comment: thx, just adding "android clickable =true" in xml file works like charm!

Answer (score 116):

There is an easy way. Put this in the TextView in XML:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Comment: Wow...didn't realize TextViews weren't clickable by default. Glad I ran across your answer. Thought I was going crazy there for a moment.

Comment: @Fernando JS, can you support detail for reason that why need set android:clickable="true"?

Comment: No. It doesn't work for me using SDK 21. The Sameer's answer worked fine.

Comment: BOSS! Worked great on Android 4.2.1. `TextView` must be not clickable by default, which makes sense. But I think later versions automatically set `clickable` to `true` when you set a `onClick` value.

Answer (score 7):

add `android:clickable="true"` in `<TextView>`

Answer (score 0):

In your onCreate method you need to:

1. Create variables for your TextViews
2. Assign the onClickListener for them

And your class also needs to implement OnClickListener.

```
public class SqliteTestsActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView all = (TextView) R.findViewById(R.id.viewall);
        all.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Fill in this with your switch statement
    }
}
```

Comment: also, is there other way to make it without implements OnClickListener at the class coz i already implements another class

Comment: First you can not implement a class, you can only implement inteface.And there is no restriction on number interface to be implement.So do not worry,implement one more interface that is onclickListener

Answer (score -1):

please make changes like this :

```
 <include  android:id = "@+id/lyttab" layout="@layout/tabs" />
```

in your Java class

```
 public void onClick(View v){   

  View view = findViewById(R.id.lyttab);

 all = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.viewall);
 pif = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pic);


switch (v){

case  all :
    Toast.makeText(Main.this, "VIEW ALL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    all.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.gradient_green));
    pic.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.white));

    break;

case pic:
    Toast.makeText(Main.this, "PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    all.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.white));
    pic.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.gradient_green));
    break;

 }
 }
```

i think this will help you

Comment: you can set only integer value in switch case not TextView directly @ramesh.Use all.getID() inplace of All