# onClick event won't trigger

Tags: java, android

I'm building a basketball score clock app.  I got the main timer working well.  When I click on it it starts the clock and when I click again it stops the clock.  This works perfect.

I've instantiated a second object that is for the shot clock.  However, the `onClick` event isn't firing at all for the second textview.

Both `onClick` events are set on a TextView element.  I have no idea why the method `onClickShotClock(View view)` is not firing when I click on the second Text View.

I know that the object is instantiated correctly because it is setting the value correctly and the value is set through the code to instantiate it.

Can anyone see what this isn't working?

```
package com.example.ultimatescoreclock;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import com.example.ultimatescoreclock.ScoreClock;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView strMainClock, strShotClock;
    ScoreClock timerMainClock, timerShotClock; 
    long msSavedMainClock = 0;
    long msSavedShotClock = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        strMainClock = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clockMain);
        strShotClock = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clockShot);

        timerMainClock = new ScoreClock( 13000, 100, strMainClock );
        timerShotClock = new ScoreClock( 8000, 100, strShotClock );

        strMainClock.setText( timerMainClock.getTimeLeft() );
        strShotClock.setText( timerShotClock.getTimeLeft() );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onMainClockClick(View view) {

        if ( !timerMainClock.isRunning ) {

            if ( msSavedMainClock != 0 )
                timerMainClock = new ScoreClock( msSavedMainClock, 100, strMainClock );

            timerMainClock.start();
            timerMainClock.isRunning = !timerMainClock.isRunning;
        } else {
            timerMainClock.cancel();
            msSavedMainClock = timerMainClock.msRemaining;
            timerMainClock.isRunning = !timerMainClock.isRunning;
        }       
    }

    public void onShotClockClick(View view) {

        strShotClock.setText("go!");
        /*
        if ( !timerShotClock.isRunning ) { 

            if ( msSavedShotClock != 0 )
                timerShotClock = new ScoreClock( msSavedShotClock, 100, strShotClock );

            timerShotClock.start();
            timerShotClock.isRunning = !timerShotClock.isRunning;
        } else {
            timerShotClock.cancel();
            msSavedShotClock = timerShotClock.msRemaining;
            timerShotClock.isRunning = !timerShotClock.isRunning;
        }
        */      
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you declare `android:onClick = "onShotClockClick"` (spelled properly) in the layout xml for that second TextView? You might want to add the xml code too. Did you try cleaning the project?

Comment: I copy and pasted it into the properties field at the side of eclipse.  I also checked the xml code to make sure it was inserted correctly.  It seems like it is there.

Comment: Well adding the xml wouldn't hurt. Also, did you try making an onClickListener programmatically?

Comment: What do you mean by "adding the XML wouldn't hurt"?  I'm new to this.  Also...  I changed the type from TextView to Button and now both of them work correctly.  Maybe there is a limitation within Android that will not allow more than one onClick event to be triggered with respect to TextView elements?

Comment: I meant adding the xml in your question. However, this isn't needed as you basically answered your own question.

Comment: Is this a known issue, or something that I have just discovered?  Maybe there is a way around it or I was trying to do something that android really isn't suppose to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [TextView onClick() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079170/textview-onclick-not-working), you need to set

> android:clickable="true"

to TextViews since they aren't clickable by default.

You can also programmatically attach OnClickListeners like so:

```
strShotClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onShotClockClick(v);            
    }
});
```