# TextView onclickListener

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener

In my application i have added textviews dynamically using array,and given id's for each with a  count variable, which increment's count according to the addition of textviews.In onClickListener of each textview i want to perform some oparations,but when i'm trying to do this operation is getting performed on all textviews.
Below is the code,i'm not getting what's wrong.please help me.

```
// here i have added textview dynamically
       mtxtview[colTextCount]=new TextView(this);
       mtxtview[colTextCount].setId(colTextCount);
       mtxtview[colTextCount].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(20,20));
```

And In onclickListener-

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    System.out.println("onclick...");

    for(jj=0;jj<_mTextViewId;jj++){
        String hh=mtxtview[jj].getText().toString();
        System.out.println("................................."+hh);     
        System.out.println("id is...."+_mTextHeight[jj].getId());
    //if i added 3 textview.its giving me all 3 textview's text(getText())  

    }

           }
```

Comment: so what is the problem/issue?

Comment: if i click on 1st textview.its giving info of all textviews.i want only 1st textview info

Comment: see [TextView onClick() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079170/textview-onclick-not-working)
You should setOnClickListener to each TextView

Answer (score 1):

use `switch-case` and `View.getId()` to check which TextView is Clicked before starting for loop . try it as :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    System.out.println("onclick...");
    switch(v.getId())
     {
       case _mTextViewId:  
         for(jj=0;jj<_mTextViewId;jj++){
          String hh=mtxtview[jj].getText().toString();
          System.out.println("................................."+hh);     
          System.out.println("id is...."+_mTextHeight[jj].getId());

         }
       break ;

      // same for others....       

    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

see [TextView onClick() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079170/textview-onclick-not-working)

You should do setOnClickListener for each TextView Object.