# How do I open an image by clicking on a text

Tags: android

i am making my very first app and i need some help please.

How do i open an image which is already preset in my app by clicking on a hyperlinked text?

I am trying to

For example,

"Refer to Image001"

when the user taps on the word "Image001", a window opens up the preset picture and it closes when i press the back button.

This is what i have so far

In strings.xml

```
<string name="refer">Refer to Image001</string>
```

In activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="@string/refer" />
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

thanks

Comment: Catherine:add listener for textview and pass image url to it..refer this it would help you..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079170/textview-onclick-not-working

Answer (score 0):

You will have to have 2 TextViews. The first one will have the text: "Refer to " and the second one will have the text "Image001". Then you set a click listener on the second textview with code like this:

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Don't forget to set clickable=true in the textview :)

Answer (score 0):

you must first set Id to your textView in xml file like below:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:gravity="left"
android:text="@string/refer" />
```

then set `setOnClickListener` for your textview like following code:

```
    TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //DO you work here
    }
});
```

after doing that in `onClick` method you can call you image like following code

```
    String url = "http://www.xxx.com";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: set clickable=true in the textview

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use [DialogFragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.htmlhttp://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.htmlhttp://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html). For example, this class extends DialogFragment and displays a picture inside ImageView.

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    public MyDialogFragment newInstance (Bitmap targetPicture) {
        MyDialogFragment frag = new MyDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putExtra("picture", targetPicture);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogfrag, container, false);
        Bitmap b = (Bitmap) getArguments().getExtra("picture");
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.targetImageView);
        iv.setImageBitmap(b);
        return v;
    }
```

However, you need to define dialogfrag.xml inside your layout folder, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/targetImageView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And finally inside your activity:

```
OnClickListener myClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        MyDialogFragment d = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(targetPicture) //replace targetPicture with the picture you want to display
        d.show();
    }
};
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
tv.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
```